# Smoothing out jittery values with thresholds

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to python. I have more experience with `c#`, so `c#` references will follow to explain.

My goal is this:

[image]

I want to put a series of time-in-ms<->boolean-value-relationships in an array or anything suitable for the next step. My starting point

`t = array([1200,2000,3000,4000,6000,7000,8000,...])`

`y = array([1,0,1,0,0,0,1,...])`

My question is about how to convert this array of numbers being represented in the upper part of the sketch into the lower part of the sketch the right way in python.

What does the sketch mean?

1. `dt1` and `dt2` are both smaller than a `dt_reference`, which is smaller than `dt3`. `dt1<dt_reference<dt3` and `dt2<dt_reference<dt3`.
2. `dt` is a given amount that is being added to the beginning and end of a block.

The output should be a list in a suitable python format, which gives me something like this:

```
Block1:Start=t1,End=t2
Block2:Start=t3,End=...
...
```

How do I do this the right way in python?

Comment: Ask this question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/ You might get a quicker response.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Your data is a-periodic?

Comment: @wwii t is progressively linear, y discreet 0 or 1.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi Good idea: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249541/smoothing-out-jittery-values-with-thresholds

Comment: So you want all the *marks* (`y==1`)to be the same width and all the *spaces* (`y==0`) to be the same width?  Do you want the *width* of the marks and spaces to be the same or will the mark width and space width be different? Won't this corrupt the information in the time series?  How do you intend to *normalize* the data? You should add that, the method might suggest the correct data type.

Comment: @wwii I want to smooth binary data. Smoothing is defined by every block "swallowing" zeroes/spaces, ie turning zeroes/spaces into ones/marks if the time difference between the previous 1/mark and the following 1/mark is below dt_reference. Having done that step with all data, I want to add more ones/marks to the beginning and end of every one-block with a width of dt.